# RPM spec missing uninstall section?

Tags: rpm, rpm-spec

I see **no uninstall** section in RPM spec documentation. I do see preun and postun.

1. Is there uninstall phase?
2. What exactly happens during uninstall phase? Basing on %files section, a list of files is removed? and that's it?

Comment: On install, the package contents, (the `%files` information), is added to the system `rpm database` (generally in `/var/lib/rpm`). On uninstall, this database information is read by `rpm` to guide the removal process.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Correct.

The `%install` section of an RPM spec file is **not** run on rpm package installation (the name is misleading in that sense). The `%install` section is run during package creation to *install* the files that need to be packaged such that the rpmbuild process can package them up.

As such, as because the `%files` section lists all the files and directories that the package contains the uninstallation process for an rpm is simply the removal of all the packaged files.

If additional work needs to be done before or after the files are removed the `%preun` and `%postun` scriptlets are available in the spec file for that work.